# Making The Console Window Somewhat Static

Tags: c, static, console

Sorry if the title is poor, I could not think of a better one.

I saw a little console memory game program written in C++ recently  that inspired me (just for the heck of it) to replicate in C (mainly for  a certian aspect of this program that stuck out to me).

It intrigued me when I saw how the console window had sort of a static effect for example if you flipped a "card":

```
//Console Screen Before "Card Flip"     
  1 2 3 
1 * * *
2 * * *
3 * * * 
Flip Which Card? (x,y): _
```

Lets say I entered `1,1` a possible output of the program may have been:

```
//Console Screen After "Card Flip"
   1 2 3 
 1 9 * *
 2 * * *
 3 * * *
 Flip Which Card? (x,y): _
```

This is actually what insipred me to replicate the program, in all honesty that's my only goal is to replicate this sort of static console.
My guess is that the author of this program just clears the screen after every user input and reprints the updated matrix (in this case the unmasked value of   1,1).

So I decided to write a sort of setup screen for the initialization of a similar program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int flips, x, y;
    do
{
    printf("*****Game Setup*****");
    printf("\n\tGrid Size (x):_");
    printf("\nGrid Size (y): ");
    printf("\nAmount of Flips (0 is Unlimited): \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    system("cls");
}
while(x <= 0);
do
{
    printf("*****Game Setup*****");
    printf("\nGrid Size(x): %d", x);
    printf("\n\tGrid Size(y):_");
    printf("\nAmount of Flips (0 is Unlmited): \n");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    system("cls");
}
while(y <= 0);
do
{
    printf("*****Game Setup*****");
    printf("\nGrid Size(x): %d", x);
    printf("\nGrid Size(y): %d", y);
    printf("\n\tAmount of Flips (0 is Unlmited):_\n");
    scanf("%d", &flips);
    system("cls");
}
while(flips < 0);
if(!flips) printf("Beginning %d by %d Memory Game with Unlimited Flips...", x ,y);
else printf("Beginning %d by %d Memory Game with %d Flips...", x, y, flips);

return 0;
}
```

It works as expected but I feel like there is probably a better way to achieve this same effect, doing it this way would increase the length of my code exponentially, and can't be efficient. Not only that but by using this method the "UI" is lousy at best, I think it would be a lot better if I could somehow just move the flashing input cursor appropriately

For Example:

```
*****Game Setup*****
Grid Size (x): _
Grid Size (y): 
...
```

Then I would enter `1` for example and the cursor would simply "move" down to the next area:

```
*****Game Setup*****
Grid Size(x): 1
Grid Size(y): _
...
```

I was thinking of accomplishing the latter with the `%n` specifier with `printf` somehow although I am not quite sure if that is even possible (I know very little about `%n`).

So is there a better way of doing this (more efficiently)?
And if so is there a way to "move" the cursor as described above?
How would YOU do something like this?

This whole concept just really peaked my curiosity.

Comment: There are ways to directly draw cells on the console.  Depends on your OS.  Smells like Windows, WriteConsoleOutputCharacter() and friends.  Curses on *nix.

Comment: If you are using Linux, do a quick search for `ncurses`. If offers you better control of the console than the standard C libraries. And also take a look at what @AdamMihalcin mentioned too.

Comment: I've heard of ncurses unfortunately I am not in a Linux environment, Kudos to Hans for his good nose ;)

Comment: There's also a decent curses library which has a Windows port, pdcurses, which I've used to port a curses application in the past.